# Providing a simulation model for a chisel blackbox

Tags: scala, chisel, chiseltest

I am trying to simulate a system using chisel 3. The system has a blackbox that has a verilog. The verilog code is not behavioural, it simply instantiate a module that the synthesizer configures.I know the behaviour of the module and want to write a code in chisel to simulate the behaviour.

So basically how to extend a blackbox in chisel 3 with a behaviour that could be used in simulation.

Comment: Why does using the Verilog code not work for you situation? `chiseltest` can simulate Verilog blackboxes as long as you pick `Verilator` as the backend. See [here for an example](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chiseltest/blob/9a9d34775f88b7c8806ad114d7532948c53a8c62/src/test/scala/chiseltest/backends/verilator/VerilogBlackBoxTest.scala)

Comment: Maybe you could also clarify what exactly you mean by "the synthesizer configures". Do you have access to the final Verilog file for your blackbox?

Comment: I am using a xpm_memory_tdpram_inst() described in this [link](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/2021.1-English/ug974-vivado-ultrascale-libraries/XPM_MEMORY_TDPRAM). It instantiates correctly a BRAM when synthesized in Vivado. However, it does not provide for Verilator any Verilog that makes sense for simulation. I am not sure that I can access the syntheized verilog by Vivado.

Comment: To elaborate more on what I want to do, looking at the code in this [link](https://github.com/maltanar/fpga-tidbits/blob/master/src/main/scala/fpgatidbits/ocm/DualPortBRAM.scala) in chisel 2, you can see in line 51 a class DualPortBRAM that extends black-box. You can see that he provides a simulation model in the black-box so that the module could be used in simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no built-in way to directly provide a behavioral model to substitute a blackbox when testing chisel3 code. However, there are some options that could work in your situation:

### Option 1: Use a Chisel `SyncReadMem` and substitute it with `--repl-seq-mem`

For memories in particular, you can used the built-in `SyncReadMem` which will work fine in all simulation and even formal verification backends. Then for your "tape-out" / FPGA synthesis you replace all synchronous read memories with Verilog code that uses the Vendor provided memory. This flow is used by the open-source [chipyard](https://chipyard.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) project for ASIC tapeout. You essentially need to pass the following flags to the firrtl compiler: `--infer-rw --repl-seq-mem` which will then automatically blackbox all `SyncReadMem` instances and generate description files for them. From these files you can write Verilog implementations using the vendor provided RTL.
*Hint*: You can use `--gen-mem-verilog` to get a blueprint for the Verilog modules you need to implement in terms of the Xilinx block.

### Option 2: Use a Chisel `SyncReadMem` and try to get BRAM interference working

You should be able to get Chisel `SyncReadMem` to be correctly inferred as BRAM by the Xilinx tool. This options is afaik used by the open-source [firesim](https://fires.im/) project to generate RTL for Xilinx FPGAs. The flags you would want to pass to the firrtl compiler are: `--infer-rw --target:fpga`

### Option 3: Use a generator parameter to choose between the behavioral and the synthesizable model

This option is the most versatile, but also requires the most work. Here is a quick draft of what that may look like:

```scala
import chisel3._


class MemIO extends Bundle {
  val addr = Input(UInt(4.W))
  val doWrite = Input(Bool())
  val dataIn = Input(UInt(8.W))
  val dataOut = Output(UInt(8.W))
}

class MemBlackBox extends BlackBox {
  val io = IO(new MemIO)

  // ...
}

class MemBehavioral extends Module {
  val io = IO(new MemIO)

  // ...
  io <> DontCare // to make things compile
}

class Memory(simulation: Boolean) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new MemIO)

  if(simulation) {
    val inner = Module(new MemBehavioral) ; inner.io <> io
  } else {
    val inner = Module(new MemBlackBox) ; inner.io <> io
  }
  
}




val pretty = Array(
  "--emission-options", "disableMemRandomization,disableRegisterRandomization"
)
println("Behavioral")
println(getVerilogString(new Memory(simulation = true), pretty))
println("\n\nSynthesizable")
println(getVerilogString(new Memory(simulation = false), pretty))
```

You can see [the output on scasti](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4vRWmx2HREioa69gfMu0uA).